# Are there two non-isomorphic modules such that all the Hom-sets are isomorphic?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $M$ and $N$ be two $R$-modules. Suppose that for every $R$-module $P$, the modules $Hom_R(M,P)$ and $Hom_R(N,P)$ are isomorphic. Is it true that $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic?

Comment: This follows from Yoneda lemma if you assume this isomorphisms are natural.

Comment: And if you do not assume the isomorphisms between Hom-sets to be natural, then for example over a field the question boils down  to whether it is possible for two non-isomorphic vector spaces to have isomorphic duals. Over the field with two elements this is simply a question about the cardinality of power sets, which might very well be independant of ZFC. 

Comment: I suggest "Are modules isomorphic if their Hom-sets are all isomorphic?" (or something like that).

Comment: @Piotr: could you please explain the "boils down" a bit further? The implication "isomorphic duals" $\implies$ "all hom spaces isomorphic" seems to require some implication of the sort $2^\kappa=2^\lambda\implies \alpha^\kappa=\alpha^\lambda$ for all cardinals $\alpha$. Is this true?

Comment: I've cleaned up this comment thread; the removed comments are copied at http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1403/some-cleaned-up-comments/.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[K. Bongartz, "A generalization of a theorem of Auslander"](http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/content/21/3/255.full.pdf+html):

> Let R be a commutative ring and A an abelian R-linear category such
>   that each morphism set in A has finite length as an R-module. Let C be a full
>   subcategory of A closed under direct sums and kernels. Then two objects M and N of
>   C are isomorphic if and only if the lengths of Hom(M, X) and Hom(N, X) coincide for
>   all X in C.